# Reference items in bash for loop from find command

Tags: bash, find, for, bash-array

Suppose I have this code:

```
for i in $(find * -type f -name "*.txt"); do 
  # echo [element by it's index]
done
```

How do I access, if possible, an element by it's index?

Comment: Where and how you define this array?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Sorry I'll try to make the question more clear. I just put `${array[0]}` as an example on how it's done if you would loop an array. What I'm asking is what would be in place of it in the above code.

Comment: The safest way to do this (to do _something_ on the things that `find` finds) is through letting `find` [execute the loop through `-exec`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705), not by [looping over the output of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command

```
$(find * -type f -name "*.txt")
```

will return a (space-separated) bash list, not an array, hence you cannot really access the individual elements in a "targeted" way.

To convert it to a bash array, use

```
filearray=( $(find * -type f -name "*.txt") )
```

(note the spaces!)

Then, you can access the individual entries as in

```
for ((i=0; i<n; i++))
do
   file="${filarray[$i]}"
   <whatever operation on the file>
done
```

where the number of entries can be retrieved via

```
n="${#filearray[@]}"
```

**Note however** that this **only** works if your file-names don't contain special characters (in particular space) and hence, once again, [parsing the output of `ls` or `find` is not recommended](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). In your case, I would recommend seeing if the `-exec` option of `find` can do what you need to accomplish.

Comment: find * ? Never read that before!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know I can create an array, my question is if it can be done without creating an array. But I guess that you answer this with *will return a (space-separated) bash list, not an array, *.

Comment: @guillermochamorro Yes, in short that is the answer, I'm afraid  ...